# socket.io crashing node on user changing pages. zlib.js:499

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm having trouble finding this crash. I have node.js and an express web app using socket.io.

When the uses refreshes the page, or moves to another page I sometimes get this crash in node:

user disconnected transport close
zlib.js:499
var newReq = self._handle.write(flushFlag,
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of null
at Zlib.callback (zlib.js:499:33)

It looks like a message is trying to be sent to a client that is no longer there. I am running node 8.2 when I see this crash. Updating to node 12 fixes it, but in production I need to use 8.2 due to hardware requirements.

I added a listener for page unload in the webapp and disconnect the socket, but the problem remains.

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to this problem!